# arithmetic on pointer to interface id which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors

i have installed xcode 4.6 and i can't built my application (it works with xcode 3.2)   :(

```
SEL sel = @selector(textField:didAddCellAtIndex:);
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:sel]) {
    [self.delegate performSelector:sel withObject:self withObject: (id)_cellViews.count-1];
}
```

help

Comment: Start with C and Objective C basics. NSUInteger is not an object.

Comment: Would help if you show us the error messages you are seeing

Comment: the error message is:  "arithmetic on pointer to interface id which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform"   in this line:  [self.delegate performSelector:sel withObject:self withObject:(id)_cellViews.count-1];

Answer (score 1):

```
withObject:(id)_cellViews.count-1
```

is where the error is. Your code casts _cellViews.count to id pointer and then substracts 1 from it.

Comment: Use object, not NSUInteger.